# sysprep failed and now I can't even log into windows now

Tags: windows-8.1, safe-mode, sysprep

Today I used sysprep.exe to rebuild my windows image. But it always said "a fatal error occurred while trying sysprep".

Then I went to check log file , it shows that "microsoft internal media playreadyclient was installed". I followed this instructions in this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2769827. The log file still shows the same thing. Of course during this period I had run multiple times of sysprep.exe.

After that I run "Get-AppxPackage -AllUser" and list all apps, and found that all apps are installed by "Unknown user". And now I even need provide permission to access my d e f partitions. I think maybe user account went wrong , and I'm exhausted , so I just enable administrator and delete my account. And I ran sysprep.exe again and still no love. So I reboot, and I forget sysprep.exe will disable administrator and now I'm in a very embarrassing situation , I can't log into windows because I delete my account and administrator is disabled. Even I input the right email and password I still can't log into windows. And I'm in uefi mode I can't enter safe mode either. Can anybody help?

Sorry for my composing , but I'm using my iPhone to post this question.........orz

Comment: Since you have D/E/F (I assume as data drives) you may be better off just wiping and starting again.

Comment: @Basic that's exactly what I don't want to do.... I have so many system related files and configurations in system partitions

Comment: If it's a case of recovering files, plug the system disk into a different machine and copy them off (or boot your machine from usb and do the same). If it's more involved (eg getting stuff out of the registry), I don't know a good answer. While this is probably not what you want to hear, next time have a backup before you start. Out of interest, do you know if the guest account is enabled on your machine?

Comment: It's disabled orz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't had to do this myself but it looks like you should be able to enable the Win8 admin account offline using the boot media...

Source (with screenshots): https://4sysops.com/archives/offline-enable-the-windows-8-built-in-administrator-account/

- Boot from the Windows 8 boot media.
- After Windows 8 setup started press SHIFT+F10 to access a command prompt.
- Type `copy /y d:\windows\system32\cmd.exe d:\windows\system32\sethc.exe`
- Remove the boot media and restart Windows 8.
- At the login screen, hit the SHIFT key five times until the command prompt appears.
- Type `net user administrator /active:yes`. This enables the built-in administrator account in Windows
- Reboot the computer. When the logon screen appears, click the arrow on the left.
- You should now see the Administrator account icon.

Comment: Excellent! The one who came up with replacing Sethc.exe must be a genius!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: But I still can't get sysprep working ,any suggestions?

Comment: No, sorry. Try asking a new question that's specific to that. Include any event log / error messages that are relevant